# Compact operators is a linear subspace of bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-verification, compact-operators

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. Let $B(X,Y)$ be the set of bounded linear operators and let $K(X,Y)$ be the set of compact linear operators.

I want to prove that $K(X,Y)$ is a vector subspace of $B(X,Y)$. Please can you check my proof?

It is clear that $0$ is a compact operator. Hence $K(X,Y)$ is not empty and contains $0$.

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, $u \in K(X,Y)$. Multiplication by $\lambda$ is a linear homeomorphism. Therefore, if $B$ denotes the unit ball in $X$, $\lambda\overline{ u(B)}$ is compact because $\overline{u(B)}$ is.

Let $u,v \in K(X,Y)$ and let $S$ be a bounded subset of $X$. The goal is to show that $\overline{u(S) + v(S)}$ is compact. To this end, note that closed subsets of compact sets are compact and that $u(S) + u(S) \subseteq \overline{u(S)} + \overline{v(S)}$. Hence it is enough to show that $\overline{u(S)} + \overline{v(S)}$ is compact:

Note that $\overline{u(S)} \times \overline{v(S)}$ is compact and that  $+: Y \times Y \to Y$ is continuous hence it maps compact sets to compact sets hence $\overline{u(S)} + \overline{v(S)}$ is compact.

Comment: $u(B)$ is relatively compact, not compact

Comment: @Norbert Thank you, it is a typo, I forgot $\overline{...}$. I will edit.

Comment: I find that the passage $$\overline{ u(B)+v(B) }\subset \overline{u(B)}+\overline{v(B)}$$ is not properly justified. Why is this true? It does not look that obvious to me. This is connected with the other unjustifed assertion, which is: "the sum of compact sets is compact". (Apart from that, the proof is fine)

Comment: Thank you for reading my proof. You are right. I will edit this part of the argument.

Comment: @Norbert I edited the proof.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I edited the proof.

Comment: It's okay, but I would prefer not to introduce the "complete and totally bounded" part. You know/show that $\overline{u(B)} + \overline{v(B)}$ is compact, and $\overline{u(B)+v(B)}$ is thus a closed subset of a compact set, hence compact.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's a good point. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure... do I also have to prove that if $u(S) + v(S) \subseteq \overline{u(S)}+\overline{v(S)}$ then $\overline{u(S) + v(S)} \subseteq \overline{u(S)}+\overline{v(S)}$ ? It would be clear if the sum of closed sets is closed because then $\overline{u(S)}+\overline{v(S)}$ would be closed.

Comment: The sum of two closed sets is in general not closed. But here you know that $\overline{u(S)}+\overline{v(S)}$ is compact, and a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed. Whether it is necessary/advisable to mention that fact, or it can be taken as well-known depends on the circumstances.